# System.String[] when datagridview is saved to csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, file-io, datagridview

This code converts datagrid view to csv file. 
This code was working fine ... but when upgrade to VS 2013 its stop working ... keeps retuning System.String[] in my Test2.txt file ..

```
Dim path As String = "D:\Test2.txt"
        r = -1
        Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() Select header.HeaderText).ToArray()
        Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(path)
            '  MsgBox(String.Join(",", headers))
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
            For Each r In rows
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
            Next
        End Using
```

Comment: You need to turn on Option Strict

Comment: VB.net is returning the object type, not the contents.  Look into the language docs and find out what the revised code is for retrieving the value of the string, not the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to write DataGridView contents to a CSV file, I'm sure you can adapt it to meet your needs:

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\Test2.txt"
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(path)
        Dim rowcontents As New List(Of String)
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            rowcontents.Add(col.HeaderText)
        Next
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowcontents))
        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            rowcontents.Clear()
            For Each c As DataGridViewCell In r.Cells
                rowcontents.Add(c.Value)
            Next
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowcontents))
        Next
    End Using
```